# Create a nice tree decomposition in python

Tags: python, networkx, decomposition

I know that networkx has a function for creating a tree decomposition:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.approximation import treewidth_min_degree

G = createGraph() # an arbitrary function returning a networkx graph
width,decomposition = treewidth_min_degree(G)
```

Is there a function transforming this tree into a **nice** tree decomposition.

Edit:
A "nice" tree decomposition is a rooted binary tree with four different types of nodes:

1. Leaf nodes have no children and bag size
2. Introduce nodes have one child. The child has the same vertices as the parent with one deleted.
3. Forget nodes have one child. The child has the same vertices as the parent with one added.
4. Join nodes have two children,
   End edit.

I know there is a linear algorithm doing this, but I wonder if this is already implemented somewhere.

Comment: I'm confused. You are saying that networkx has a function for creating a tree decomposition, and then you ask if there is a function which creates a tree decomposition. What's the difference between the function from networkx and the function you are looking for?

Comment: Is there a special definition for "nice tree"? (I haven't seen this before.)

Comment: I am looking for a "nice" decomposition. Definition. A "nice" tree decomposition is a rooted binary tree with four different types
of nodes: 1. Leaf nodes have no children.      2. Introduce nodes have one child. The child has the same vertices as the parent with one deleted.     3. Forget nodes have one child. The child has the same vertices as the parent with one added.     4. Join nodes have two children, both identical to the parent.